# Why scrollContentsBy(dx, dy) function not called when scroll by moving the cursor in QPlainTextEdit

Tags: qt, qt4, qplaintextedit

I have derived the QPlaintTextEdit and override the scrollContentsBy function. This gets called only when we use mouse-wheel or scrollbar. When we use arrow-keys to move the cursor and scroll content by that, this function does not get called.

I have done the same thing for QTextEdit, it works fine (means, it get called in all situations).

What is the reason for this behavior? and what is the alternative I can use?

NOTE: This is the function prototype

```
void QPlainTextEdit::scrollContentsBy ( int dx, int dy ) [virtual protected]
```

Environment:

- Windows 7
- Qt 4.8
- VS 2008

Update:
None of the following alternatives are working,

- valueChanged
- sliderMoved

Comment: No idea why, but maybe you can solve yours problem with connecting directly to QScrollBar::valueChanged()? It will be emitted in any case, I think.

Comment: `scrollContentsBy` is designed for render optimization and there is not much harm if it's not triggered in some cases. Just use `QScrollBar::valueChanged` instead.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov, valueChanged also not emitted :(

Comment: Does the scroll bar move visually when you do this?

Comment: @PavelStrakhov, Yeah, that is the strange thing.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Try it in Qt 5.4.